# jQuery get value of a input field attribute

Tags: jquery

I cannot seem to get the test in the 'Value' field

```
<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl01$ctl12$ctl00$HiddenUserFieldValue" type="hidden" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01_ctl12_ctl00_HiddenUserFieldValue" value="24;#Ryan,, C,#i:0#.f|membership|cryan@corp.blah.net,#CRyan@blah.com,#C_Ryan@blah.com,#Ryan,, C">
```

How can get the data in the value field?

Thanks.. I know this should be easy but I'm about to shoot myself.

Comment: `$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01_ctl12_ctl00_HiddenUserFieldValue").val()`

Comment: data value ? or just a value ? ?

Comment: `#id` must be lowercase, so that is the reason why you cannot get the value of the element by id.

Comment: What's going on there? Why such long values?

Comment: @HenryW That's not at all [accurate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html#answer-79022)...

Comment: @Vohuman Looks like the fields are generated by a CMS. SharePoint generates similar type field names...

Comment: @Vohuman my guess is dynamically generated content from a CMS. They tend to have horrendous encrypted-looking IDs and whatnots.

Comment: yes i am very sorry, i meant special chars. But that is not the case here.Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to fetch the element's value by id in jQuery. Check your output in console.

```js
console.log($("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01_ctl12_ctl00_HiddenUserFieldValue").val());
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl01$ctl12$ctl00$HiddenUserFieldValue" type="hidden" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01_ctl12_ctl00_HiddenUserFieldValue" value="24;#Ryan,, C,#i:0#.f|membership|cryan@corp.blah.net,#CRyan@blah.com,#C_Ryan@blah.com,#Ryan,, C">
```

Answer (score 1):

as id is there you should use # before the ID

```
var myval = $("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01_ctl12_ctl00_HiddenUserFieldValue").val();
```

Comment: Don't use `alert` as a debug statement, use `console.log`

Comment: Very true, or you could just follow typical debugging convention and be a good developer ;)

Comment: you can do anything, you can consol.log , you can use alert , you can store the value in any  variable , but the thing is  using this you got the value.  am i right  ?

Comment: try console logging an array, and alert()'ing the same array. It's not the same.